# Replace number in E26 cell reference with formula

Tags: excel, ms-office

In Excel I have a formula that would reference another cell with $E$26 would it be possible to replace the 26 with another formula?
For example I want to make it to where the formula looks like this $E$(SUM(25, 1)) does excel allow this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `INDEX` with `MATCH`.`INDEX(E:E,MATCH(C6, A1:A36, 0))`

Comment: I want to find a way to add just a formula into that spot. The exact formula that I want to use is a little bit longer and I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Nope, not possible. As I suggested, use `INDEX`.